# show Lync contacts in Sharepoint 2013 sharepoint hosted app

Tags: sharepoint, lync

I want to get the list of contacts from my Lync and show it in SharePoint 2013 using sharepoint hosted app (JSOM). Could anyone please help me out on this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Lync (now Skype for Business) integrates with Active Directory, as does SharePoint - i.e. you will get status updates, etc - depending on if you are talking about an account for a company or not.  Please expand your question.

Comment: Hi Brian, My requirement is my sharepoint app should show the contacts from the my contact list of lync based on current logged in user in my organization.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great site that outlines the technical options for interacting/extending Lync.  I believe you are going to have to develop some custom code based on your initial requirement that you outline above:
http://www.codelync.com/an-overview-of-the-lync-apis/

The Microsoft Lync SDK is here: 
[Microsoft Lync 2010 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18898)

Also, be aware that Lync is now branded "Skype for Business" and you will want to take that into account in reviewing the available API's.